# Small parameter expansion of an integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I am trying analyze an integral of the form

$$I(\varepsilon)=\int_0^\infty f(t,\varepsilon) \,dt$$

where $\varepsilon$ is a small real parameter. The function $f(t,\varepsilon)$ is very complicated, so the integral cannot be evaluated analytically, but it is enough for me to understand its behavior around $\varepsilon=0$. The function $f(t,\varepsilon)$ has a Taylor expansion
$f(t,\varepsilon) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(t) \varepsilon^n$,
so the naive answer would be $I(\varepsilon)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \varepsilon^n\int_0^\infty f_n(t) \, dt$.

However, some of the integrals $\int_0^\infty f_n(t) \, dt$ in the series diverge (to be more specific, the integrands behave as $e^{-t}t^{-m}$, so the integrals diverge around 0). Is there any way to compute the expansion in such case? I have tried various substitutions, division of the integral into several parts, etc., but I always get some kind of divergent or ambiguous result.

As a simple example, consider the integral

$$I(\varepsilon)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\varepsilon\, e^{-t}}{t^2+\varepsilon^2} \, dt$$

This integral can be evaluated explicitly using special functions and its expansion is

$$I(\varepsilon)=\frac{\pi }{2}+\varepsilon (\log(\varepsilon ) + \gamma -1)+\cdots$$

The expansion of the integrand is
$$\frac{\varepsilon\, e^{-t}}{t^2+\varepsilon^2}=\frac{e^{-t} \varepsilon}{t^2}
-\frac{e^{-t} \varepsilon^3}{t^4}+\frac{e^{-t} \varepsilon ^5}{t^6}+\cdots,$$ which means that integrals of all terms in the series diverge. I would like to know how to get the expansion of $I(\varepsilon)$ without computing $I(\varepsilon)$ explicitly.

Comment: do the change of variable $t=\epsilon s$.

Comment: One thing is for certain: you cannot obtain the $\varepsilon \log \varepsilon$ term using solely a power series expansion.

Comment: This expansion of the integrand is pointless since the main contribution to the integral comes from $t\lesssim\epsilon$, but then nothing gets small in the series.

Comment: I don't think there can be a general method for the general problem. In the example, one way saying it is that you are trying to expand the harmonic (on $\mathbb C^+$) function $u(x,y)=P*e^{-|t|}$ about $(0,0)$, along vertical directions $(0,\epsilon)$. However, since $e^{-|t|}$ is not smooth at $t=0$, power series expansions are ruled out.

Comment: This question is too general. But it seems like the notion of asymptotic expansion might help.

Comment: A general idea is deformation of the contour of integration. This probably works best if we write $I(\epsilon)=\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-\epsilon\tan x}\, dx$ (substitution $t=\epsilon\tan x$). The integrand is holomorphic away from the zeros $\pi/2+n\pi$ of cosine, and the contribution from near $x\simeq \pi/2$ to the integral is negligible. So for example, we can go up the imaginary axis, then parallel to the real axis, and then back to $\pi/2$ on $\textrm{Re }z=\pi/2$. The first two integrals are holomorphic in $\epsilon$, so we have in effect replaced the integral over $(0,\pi/2)$ (cont'd)

Comment: by one over $\pi/2+it$, $0\le t\le T$. I didn't manage to get any mileage out of this here, though.

Answer (score 1):

Write $$I(\epsilon)=\epsilon\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-s}}{\epsilon^2+s^2}, ds +\epsilon\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-s}}{\epsilon^2+s^2}, ds =: J(\epsilon)+K(\epsilon).$$
Then $$J(\epsilon)=\epsilon \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n s^n}{n!(\epsilon^2+s^2)}\, ds= \arctan \epsilon^{-1}-\frac {\epsilon}{2}\log (1+\epsilon^{-2})+\epsilon \sum_{n \geq 2}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^1 \frac{s^n}{\epsilon^2+s^2}\, ds
$$
so that
$J(\epsilon) \approx \frac \pi 2-\epsilon+\epsilon \log \epsilon +\epsilon \sum_{n \geq 2}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(n-1)}+O(\epsilon)^2$.
Also
$$
K(\epsilon)=\epsilon \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-s}}{s^2(1+\epsilon^2 s^{-2})}\, ds=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \epsilon^{2n+1}\frac{e^{-s}}{s^{2n+2}}\, ds=\epsilon \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-s}}{s^2}\, ds+O(\epsilon^2).
$$
Summing all together $$I(\epsilon)=\frac \pi 2+\epsilon \log \epsilon +\epsilon \left (\sum_{n \geq 2}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(n-1)}+\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-s}}{s^2}\, ds -1 \right )+O(\epsilon^2).$$

Comment: Curiously, the value of the series and the value of the integral , according to Maple, have no simple expression; yet their sum does, namely just the Euler-Mascheroni  constant.

Comment: Yes, but I do not now a proof...

Comment: The sum is $\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x}+x-1}{x^2}dx$ (integrate term-wise), and the integral of $\frac{e^{-s}}{s^2}$ can be transformed, via integration by parts, to the integral of $\frac{e^{-s}}{s}$. And now the expression in the brackets can be computed from the known asymptotics for the exponential integral ($\gamma$ comes from $Ei(x) = - \gamma - \log(x) + O(x)$ for small $x$).

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov Thank you, this closes the gap.

Comment: Thank you, I will try whether this approach helps me with the actual function I am trying to expand.

Comment: If someone is interested in an example closer to the actual problem, you can try to analyze integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-t+\frac{2\pi i}{1+t/\epsilon}}R(t,\epsilon)$, where $R(t,\epsilon)$ is some rational function of both variables. This case is more difficult due to more complicated argument of the exponential.

Comment: You should give the explicit $R$ you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Some partial progress: following the suggestion in the comments, make the substitution $t\mapsto \varepsilon t$ to arrive at the integral
$$I(\varepsilon) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\varepsilon t}}{1+t^2}\,dt$$
Now, consider first the portion of the integral over $[0,1/\varepsilon]$,
\begin{aligned}
g(\varepsilon)= \int_0^{1/\varepsilon} \frac{e^{-\varepsilon t}}{1+t^2}\,dt.
\end{aligned}
You can show that the remaining part over $[1/\varepsilon, \infty)$ is $O(\varepsilon^2)$. Using limits as necessary, we have that
$$g(\varepsilon)-g(0)= \int_0^{1/\varepsilon} \frac{e^{-\varepsilon t}-1}{1+t^2}\,dt - \varepsilon + O(\varepsilon^2). $$
Then, note that
$$\int_0^{1/\varepsilon} \frac{e^{-\varepsilon t}-1}{1+t^2}\,dt=\int_0^{1/\varepsilon}\frac{-\varepsilon t}{1+t^2}dt +O(\varepsilon)=\varepsilon \log(\varepsilon)+ O(\varepsilon).$$
At least, this calculation shows how to get the $\varepsilon \log(\varepsilon)$ in the expansion. What is left is to show that
$$\int_0^{1/\varepsilon}\frac{e^{-\varepsilon t}-1}{1+t^2}\,dt = -\varepsilon \log(\varepsilon) + \gamma \varepsilon+ O(\varepsilon^2).$$